Mutability of numpy arrays and Python lists as function arguments
I'd like advice on how numpy arrays and Python lists are passed into functions.  Specifically, VBA and other languages I'm familiar with can be explicit in the function definition if an argument is passed byVal or byRef.  Python seems confusing at best, since it seems to pass arguments byVal (in effect) unless the argument is mutable, in which it passed byRef (in effect).  However, I don't understand how this works with mutable arrays and lists.  Is my thinking about the equivalence of mutable/immutable with byRef/byVal just wrong?  Should I .deepcopy() any array parameters in a the fist line of a function to eliminate the risk of unintended consequences?
This hopefully shows what I mean with a numpy array (same thing happens with a Python list being modified though a comprehension rather than a loop on each element):
import numpy as np

def inc_elements(my_array):
    for i in range(len(my_array)):
        my_array[i] = my_array[i] + 1.0
        # same effect as: my_array[i] += 1.0
    return my_array

def inc_array(my_array):
    my_array = np.add(my_array, np.full_like(my_array, 1.0))
    # same effect as: my_array = my_array + np.full_like(my_array, 1.0)
    # and:            my_array = my_array + 1.0
    # but NOT:        my_array += 1.0
    return my_array

def del_element(my_array):
    my_array = np.delete(my_array, [0,])
    return my_array

functions = [inc_elements, inc_array, del_element]
for func in functions:
    old_array = np.array([0., 1., 2.])
    print(f'old_array = {old_array}, {type(old_array)}')
    new_array = func(old_array)
    print(f'after {func.__name__}:')
    print(f'new array = {new_array}, {type(new_array)}')
    print(f'old_array = {old_array}, {type(old_array)}\n')
    del old_array, new_array

old_array = [0. 1. 2.], <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
after inc_elements:
new array = [1. 2. 3.], <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
old_array = [1. 2. 3.], <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
old_array = [0. 1. 2.], <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
after inc_array:
new array = [1. 2. 3.], <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
old_array = [0. 1. 2.], <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
old_array = [0. 1. 2.], <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
after del_element:
new array = [1. 2.], <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
old_array = [0. 1. 2.], <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
It appears that the elements of the argument array are mutable, so if I change them one at a time with inc_elements, the values also change in the argument to my function, but the array itself is not (?), so if I use a numpy function to change the whole array in inc_array or del_element (even if only modifies the elements of the array), it does not change the argument to my function.  Is this generally true?  I would like to understand because I will have cases where I pass a sub-array, or even just one element of an array, into a function, and I would also like to know if the same applies to all other numpy functions, e.g. replace:
    my_array = np.add(my_array, np.full_like(my_array, 1.0))

with any other function such as:
    my_array = np.sqrt(my_array)

I've also noted that the augmented assignment operator a += b applied to a numpy array behaves like the looped function and is not equivalent to a = a + b, which I had not expected.
Can anyone recommend a decent text-book (or link) that can explain in depth how array and list arguments are passed to python functions?
Many thanks.

The diagrams in this article make it really clear imo: https://medium.com/@devyjoneslocker/understanding-pythons-pass-by-assignment-in-the-backdrop-of-pass-by-value-vs-9f5cc602f943

It's very simple: all objects in Python are passed to functions in exactly the same way. The method has an esoteric name, "call by sharing", but basically, it works exactly like assignment to local variables (the parameters)

Python never uses pass by value. But note, you wouldn't be able to tell if it did or not unless you are working with mutable arguments. Note, it never uses pass by reference either.

"so if I use a numpy function to change the whole array in inc_array or del_element (even if only modifies the elements of the array), it does not change the argument to my function." Neither of those functions mutates the array

Save yourself some confusion by not reusing the my_array name in your functions.  Also read up on the scope of local variables.  Whether an operation mutates an array or creates a new one applies outside a function just as much as inside.  And keep the numpy docs handy.

Lists have a number of methods that mutate in-place, like append.  Arrays have fewer - mainly indexed asjgnment and operators like +=.  However some methods may return a view (e.g. reshape). Readup on numpy view/copy.  Otherwise most numpy functions return a new array, especially anything documented as a ufunc.

np.sort function returns a new array, while the equivalent method operates in place.  Docs are clear about. Following the [source] link I see that the function calls a = asanyarray(a).copy(order="K") and then applies the sort method.  The sorted copy is returned.
